# How to convert JSON string to JSON in Oracle

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I need to convert JSON string to JSON in Oracle query.

**Example String:**

```
{\"1\":{\"qid\":1,\"aid\":1,\"a\":\"Yes\",\"isdyn\":0},\"2\":{\"qid\":2,\"aid\":7,\"a\":\"sdfbsjkb\",\"isdyn\":1},\"3\":{\"qid\":2,\"aid\":7,\"a\":\"sdfbsjkb\",\"isdyn\":1}}
```

and then store into an Oracle Column Table with a constraint of Valid JSON.

How can I do the same in Oracle and what is the best approach?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adjsn/toc.htm)

Comment: Going through this page now, Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Oracle by itself has no meaning. Even Oracle 12c has no meaning. What is your full version number? The answer will likely depend on that.

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Use `REPLACE` to remove those backslashes before quotes. You could then insert them into a table and store it as a normal JSON.

```
CREATE TABLE t_json (
     id         INTEGER
          GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
     json_col   CLOB
          CONSTRAINT ensure_json CHECK ( json_col IS JSON ) --Is a valid json
);

INSERT INTO t_json ( json_col )
     SELECT replace('{\"1\":{\"qid\":1,\"aid\":1,\"a\":\"Yes\",\"isdyn\":0},\"2\":{\"qid\":2,\"aid\":7,\"a\":\"sdfbsjkb\",\"isdyn\":1},\"3\":{\"qid\":2,\"aid\":7,\"a\":\"sdfbsjkb\",\"isdyn\":1}}'
    ,'\"','"')
     FROM dual;

1 row inserted.
```

Access the elements

```
select t.json_col."1".a from t_json t;

A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
----
Yes
```

Comment: Using the same approach, however, what if there is a special character in actual JSON like`\"a\":\"Yes\#\"` then `\#`  also needs to be replaced with `#`. I think when JSON object is converted to JSON string the \ is appended with every special character. So, the logic will be like `replace(\ any special character,any special character)`. Please suggest.

Comment: @Tajinder : You question is more about how to transform the string rather than converting to JSON. This question answers your original question. You may try `REGEXP_REPLACE( '\"a\":\"Yes\#\"' ,'\\(["#])','\1')` to replace anything followed by backlash with just the character itself. If you have more things to be replaced/modified, try and ask a separate question with proper details.You may accept this answer if you think it helped you.

Comment: Sorry if the question was not clear. The string given in the question was just an example. Hoping it is clear now. I have also edited the question. You can check and suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
with input as ( select
'{\"1\":{\"qid\":1,\"aid\":1,\"a\":\"Yes\",\"isdyn\":0},\"2\":{\"qid\":2,\"aid\":7,\"a\":\"sdfbsjkb\",\"isdyn\":1},\"3\":{\"qid\":2,\"aid\":7,\"a\":\"sdfbsjkb\",\"isdyn\":1}}'
txt
from dual
)
select json_value(
  '["' || txt || '"]',
  '$[0]'
  error on error
) json_txt
from input;
```

{"1":{"qid":1,"aid":1,"a":"Yes","isdyn":0},"2":{"qid":2,"aid":7,"a":"sdfbsjkb","isdyn":1},"3":{"qid":2,"aid":7,"a":"sdfbsjkb","isdyn":1}}

JSON_VALUE just unescaped everything for you.

Best regards,
Stew Ashton